# Fatal Error in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, fatal-error

After I upgrade to Unity 4.5 it always crashed. I always have this Fatal Error Message.

> Fatal Error
>
> !m_PathToGUID.insert (make_pair (trashPathGood, guid)).second

I don't really know why it happened, but I'm hoping you can help me here.

Comment: Try uninstalling unity and installing it again

Comment: Yeah I tried that one still the same. But after I upgrade to 4.5.1 it was fixed. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Throw your computer away and buy a new one

Comment: @Savlon Yeah I think I will throw this. I got this error again and again. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all directories and files except Assets and ProjectSettings, and open the project again.